# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js): HookWebpackError: Module build failed

Tags: angular, nebular

I am updating angular 12 to angular 15 with nebular theme. In override.scss I declared a @function. Sass loader cant build the module and showing this error-

./src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js): HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: $color: rgba(var(--color-basic-1100), 0.08) is not a color.

Can anyone help me out please?

I am trying to build the project. But it shows the error every single time.